# using sprintf to print out stings on a LCD how can i use a percent sign in this function

Tags: c, io, format, printf, percentage

Hello I am new to most coding and i am writing code onto PSoC4 creator for PSoC 3 chip that uses sprintf to display a string to LCD but my function looks like

```
sprintf(line1Str,"Local T" );           //TOP row of LCD                        
sprintf(line2Str,"TL=%.1f", CurrentTemp ) //Bottom row of LCD
```

My problem is that i want to be able to display the % sign in this as well as floating point.
I have tried the special character stuff like Char38 and so forth and leaving white space and such but it seams to skip when i have this style of format. can anyone help me?

Comment: Use two percent signs `%%`.

Comment: actually njeeds 3 %. Two to get the % , one to get the float value

Answer (score 1):

To display the `%` character in a string created or outputted by a  printf-family function, use the `%%` escape sequence:

```
printf("Your grade is 100%% on this assignment\n");
```

Output:

```
Your grade is 100% on this assignment
```

See [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), particularly the last entry in the first table:

> A % followed by another % character will write a single % to the stream.

Comment: Thanks I tried the double %% infront of it with the call to the float but not after thanks its working now much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `%%` like this:

```
sprintf(line2Str,"TL=%%%.1f", CurrentTemp );
```

Note that need one percentage character for the float number as well.

Comment: needs 3 not 2..

Comment: @GovindParmar see my update is that what you are saying? Nice answer BTW of yours. If you feel like it, I can delete mine. Yes that's it pm100, thanks!